# How to find out in which Wiki software a website is built on?

Tags: wiki

Some websites have a small logo or something at the bottom of their web page indicating that for example, that website is powered by MediaWiki.

How to find out what Wiki software does a website use in case of the owner removing the "Powered by ..." logo?

Answer (score 0):

To check for mediawiki sites, I check for the Special:Version page. For example, https://codex.wordpress.org/Special:Version.

Answer (score 0):

Find out, which technologies a particular website is using with [w3techs.com](https://w3techs.com/sites)